# Using Pivot relations in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've the following tables:

1.`institute_codes`

| id | institute_id | course_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 45 | ABCD |

2.`code_claims`

| id | code_id | user_id | approved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 |

The `institute_codes` and `code_claims` are pivot tables. I want to retrieve `users` details based on the `user_id` column in `code_claims` and the `course` information which corresponds to the used code(code_id in `code_claims` table).

I've the following relationships till now:

```
class InstituteCode extends Pivot
{  
use HasFactory;

protected $table = ['institute_codes'];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'code_claims', 'code_id');
}
}


class User extends Model
{
      public function codes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(InstituteCode::class, 'code_claims');
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

So what exactly is your question here? :)

Your relationships are all messed up. I would read into the Laravel documentation first on relationships.

A basic has many / belongs to relationship is important, but also this one might be very interesting in your situation:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Also take note of the foreign key conventions below it.

One important tip is that the BelongsTo relation should always go in the model of the table with the foreign key (f.e. user_id). This way you can not go wrong.

Comment: I've a small form where user can simply put the code(ex. ABCD). Now this entry must me registered in code_claims. And the institute which owns the code(institute_id) must be notified that the following user has  applied for `this` course. Now, how can I can fetch the users information and the course information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).